# Will doxygen use base class docs if a sub-class doesn't provide its own?

Tags: doxygen

If I have a class:

```
class Base
{
 public:
  ///does something
  virtual void method()=0;
};
class Child : public Base
{
 public:
  virtual void method();
};
```

What will doxygen do for `Child::method`? Reuse the base docs, or leave it blank?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on the INHERIT_DOCS configuration setting. When setting INHERIT_DOCS to YES the documentation will be copied, when setting it to NO the derived method will remain undocumented.